# GAS: JMP instruction incorrect?

Tags: macos, assembly, gnu-assembler

I have this assembly code:

**jit_out.s**

```
movq $0x1, %rax
jmp f1
movq $0xf000000101db3fb1, %rsi
push %rsi
movq $0x101db3ed8, %rax
addq $8, %rsp
ret
f1:
movq $0x101db3fb0, %rax
movq $0x1, %rax
ret
```

Running `as -v < /dev/null` gives:

```
Apple Inc version cctools-862, GNU assembler version 1.38
```

Running `as jit_out.s -o jit_out.o` and `objdump -D jit_out.o` returns:

```
jit_out.o:     file format mach-o-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

    0000000000000000 <f1-0x26>:
   0:   48 c7 c0 01 00 00 00    mov    $0x1,%rax
   7:   e9 00 00 00 00          jmpq   c <f1-0x1a>
   c:   48 be b1 3f db 01 01    movabs $0xf000000101db3fb1,%rsi
  13:   00 00 f0 
  16:   56                      push   %rsi
  17:   48 b8 d8 3e db 01 01    movabs $0x101db3ed8,%rax
  1e:   00 00 00 
  21:   48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
  25:   c3                      retq   

0000000000000026 <f1>:
  26:   48 b8 b0 3f db 01 01    movabs $0x101db3fb0,%rax
  2d:   00 00 00 
  30:   48 c7 c0 01 00 00 00    mov    $0x1,%rax
  37:   c3                      retq
```

The bit that is confusing me is this line:

```
  7:    e9 00 00 00 00          jmpq   c <f1-0x1a>
```

Why does it jump to location c (the next instruction?) rather than 26, have I read that correctly?

Comment: Try `objdump -dr` and see if there is a relocation entry.

Comment: Try using `objdump -r just_out.o`.  You'll probably find a relocation targetting the jump instruction that will be fixed up by the linker to point to `f1`.

Comment: Aha, that works. It now outputs this:
`1: BRANCH32 f1_0x105425148`

How do I make the linker apply the relocation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out using `as -L` on OSX fixes up the relocation!